# C#, o que são métodos, classes, e objetos?

Tags: c#, classes, método, objetos

Quais são as diferenças entre os três? Além deles têm mais alguma? 
Sou nova na área de desenvolvimento, e quero aprender mais.

Answer (score -1):

**Propriedades**: Conjunto de características de uma determinada classe.

**Métodos**: Comportamentos de uma classe, seriam equivalentes a funções em uma linguagem de programação estruturada.

**Construtor**: Inicializa um objeto com as propriedades passadas.

**Classe**: Conjunto de métodos e propriedades que definem um escopo.
**Objeto**: Um elemento com características definidos por uma classe.

```
public class Pessoa //Aqui é a classe e a definição de suas propriedades e comportamentos (métodos)
{
   private string Nome {get; set;}; //Propriedades da classe

   public Pessoa(string _nome) //Construtor
   {
      nome= _nome;
   }

   public string FalaNome() //Método que fala o seu nome
   {
       return "Meu nome é " + nome;
   }
}

static void Main()
{
    var pessoa = new Pessoa("Felipe"); //Aqui definimos um objeto da classe Pessoa com o nome Felipe
    Console.WriteLine(pessoa.FalaNome()); //Imprime Meu nome é Felipe no console
}
```